# How to get day of week on left side of D3 calendar heat map

Tags: d3.js, d3heatmap

I'm trying to create a calendar heatmap with D3, very similar to the Github contribution calendar.

I can't get the day of week to align correctly.  It seems to repeat for every month and doesn't have correct margins or alignment.  I only want the days to display once, on the left side of the calendar.

Just like this:

[image]

Here is what mine looks like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<style>
#calendar {
  margin: 20px;
}
.month {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.month-name {
  font-size: 85%;
  fill: #777;
  font-family: Muli, san-serif;
}
.day.hover {
  stroke: #6d6E70;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
.day.focus {
  stroke: #ffff33;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
</style>
<div style="text-align:center;" id="calendar"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

function drawCalendar(dateData){

  var weeksInMonth = function(month){
    var m = d3.timeMonth.floor(month)
    return d3.timeWeeks(d3.timeWeek.floor(m), d3.timeMonth.offset(m,1)).length;
  }

  //var minDate = new Date(2018, 12, 31);
  var minDate = d3.min(dateData, function(d) { return new Date(2018, 12, 1 ) });
  //var minDate = d3.min(dateData, function(d) { return new Date(d.day) });
  console.log(minDate);
  //var maxDate = new Date(2019, 11, 30);
  var maxDate = d3.max(dateData, function(d) { return new Date(2019, 11, 30 ) });
  console.log(maxDate);

  var cellMargin = 2,
      calY=10,//offset of calendar in each group
      xOffset=-5,
      dayName = ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'],
      cellSize = 20;

  var day = d3.timeFormat("%w"),
      week = d3.timeFormat("%U"),
      format = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"),
      titleFormat = d3.utcFormat("%a, %d-%b"),
      monthName = d3.timeFormat("%B"),
      months= d3.timeMonth.range(d3.timeMonth.floor(minDate), maxDate);

  var svg = d3.select("#calendar").selectAll("svg")
    .data(months)
    .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("class", "month")
    .attr("height", ((cellSize * 7) + (cellMargin * 8) + 20) ) // the 20 is for the month labels
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      var columns = weeksInMonth(d);
      return ((cellSize * columns) + (cellMargin * (columns + 1)));
    })
    .append("g")


  svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "month-name")
    .attr("y", (cellSize * 7) + (cellMargin * 8) + 15 )
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      var columns = weeksInMonth(d);
      return (((cellSize * columns) + (cellMargin * (columns + 1))) / 2);
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return monthName(d); })


 //create day labels
        var days = ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'];
        var dayLabels=svg.append("g").attr("id","dayLabels")
        days.forEach(function(d,i)    {
            dayLabels.append("text")
            .attr("class","dayLabel")
            .attr("x",xOffset)
            .attr("y",function(d) { return calY+(i * cellSize); })
            .text(d);
        })



  var rect = svg.selectAll("rect.day")
    .data(function(d, i) { return d3.timeDays(d, new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, 1)); })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "day")
    .attr("width", cellSize)
    .attr("height", cellSize)
    .attr("rx", 3).attr("ry", 3) // rounded corners
    .attr("fill", '#eaeaea') // default light grey fill
    .attr("y", function(d) { return (day(d) * cellSize) + (day(d) * cellMargin) + cellMargin; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return ((week(d) - week(new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),1))) * cellSize) + ((week(d) - week(new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),1))) * cellMargin) + cellMargin ; })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).classed('hover', true);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).classed('hover', false);
    })
    .datum(format);

  rect.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return titleFormat(new Date(d)); });

  var lookup = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.day; })
    .rollup(function(leaves) {
      return d3.sum(leaves, function(d){ return parseInt(d.count); });
    })
    .object(dateData);

  var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(dateData, function(d) { return parseInt(d.count); }))
    .range([0.2,1]); // the interpolate used for color expects a number in the range [0,1] but i don't want the lightest part of the color scheme

  rect.filter(function(d) { return d in lookup; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d3.interpolateYlGn(scale(lookup[d])); })
    .select("title")
    .text(function(d) { return titleFormat(new Date(d)) + ":  " + lookup[d]; });

}

d3.csv("dates.csv", function(response){
  drawCalendar(response);
})


</script>
```

There is also an input csv file that contains the following values:

```
day,count
2019-05-12,171
2019-06-17,139
2019-05-02,556
2019-04-10,1
2019-05-04,485
2019-03-27,1
2019-05-26,42
2019-05-25,337
2019-05-23,267
2019-05-05,569
2019-03-31,32
2019-03-25,128
2019-05-13,221
2019-03-30,26
2019-03-15,3
2019-04-24,10
2019-04-27,312
2019-03-20,99
2019-05-10,358
2019-04-01,15
2019-05-11,199
2019-07-06,744
2019-05-08,23
2019-03-28,98
2019-03-29,64
2019-04-30,152
2019-03-21,148
2019-03-19,20
2019-05-07,69
2019-04-29,431
2019-04-25,330
2019-04-28,353
2019-04-18,9
2019-01-10,1
2019-01-09,2
2019-03-26,21
2019-05-27,18
2019-04-19,10
2019-04-06,1
2019-04-12,214
2019-05-03,536
2019-07-03,3
2019-06-16,1
2019-03-24,138
2019-04-26,351
2019-04-23,14
2019-05-01,19
2019-07-05,523
2019-05-22,3
2019-05-09,430
2019-05-24,472
2019-04-11,172
2019-03-17,7
2019-05-14,10
2019-05-06,449
2019-07-04,295
2019-05-15,12
2019-03-23,216
2019-03-18,47
2019-03-22,179
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you allow for a margin in your SVG, something like this:

```
  const margin = { top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 10, left: 5 }
  const svg = d3
      .select('#chart')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 900 + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
```

Basically you create an SVG element that is bigger than your drawing area, and then you move (translate) the chart in by the margins. Then your axis can appear in the margin

Comment: This code snippet actually made my chart disappear completely.

Comment: Did you get some kind of console error? DId you just paste it in, or adapt it for your code?

Comment: I did not receive any errors...I tried adapting to my code but obviously failed.  I've been trying to get this to work for 2 days now.

Comment: To be honest, I got so frustrated with it that I had to step away.

Comment: You know I am the opposite, I have to master these things :)

Comment: haha!  I'll work on putting a codepen together.  I do want to figure it out :)

Comment: It sounds like we are committed to winning now :)

Comment: Thank you for holding me accountable.  I've never used codepen before but I set one up here: https://codepen.io/beechwood/pen/RwNVEgd  There is also an input CSV file with dates and values with the following format:  day,count
2019-05-12,171
2019-06-17,139
2019-05-02,556
2019-04-10,1
2019-05-04,485
2019-03-27,1
2019-05-26,42
2019-05-25,337
2019-05-23,267
2019-05-05,569
2019-03-31,32
2019-03-25,128
2019-05-13,221
2019-03-30,26

Comment: This is my code before adding any of your suggestions.  :)

Comment: It doesn't even run - can you please fix it as a starting point?

Comment: LOL, yes.  I have a feeling it's because the data is coming from an input file (which is missing) instead of a json array within the code.  Let me fix it.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Hello, I have fixed the codepen.  Thanks for your patience :)